# How to g.drawString, variables using AWT - Java

Tags: java, string, applet, awt

I want to display a double variable on the screen, using the paint () in AWT applets.
I tried using

```
g.drawString (double, 1, 700, 400, 300);
```

This gives me an error. Any help.
Is there any other way to put variables on the screen.

Comment: If you're seeing an error from your code and asking a question about it, it would make sense to post that error message, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Graphics#drawString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) only accepts a `String` value (there is also a varient that accepts `AttributedCharacterIterator`, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you're trying to use).  Also, `Graphics#drawString` only takes three parameters, a `String` or `AttributedCharacterIterator` and two `int` values...

You could use `Double.toString` or `NumberFormat` to convert the value to a `String`, depending on what you are trying to achieve

```
g.drawString(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(doubleValue), 100, 100);
```

You may also want to take a look at [`FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) to better calculate the position of the text

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable `x` which is not a `String`, you can convert it to a `String` and render it using:

```
g.drawString(String.valueOf(x), 1, 700, 400, 300);
```